# JS total time calculation

Tags: javascript, time

#### JSON file:

```
[   {
        "action1": "enter",
        "time": "13.00"
    },
    {
        "action2": "exit",
        "time": "13.20"
    },
    {
        "action1": "enter",
        "time": "13.50"
    },
    {
        "action2": "exit",
        "time": "15.00"
    },
    {
        "action1": "enter",
        "time": "16.00"
    },
    {
        "action2": "exit",
        "time": "20.00"
    }
]
```

What I want:
Find the difference between total input and total output

How can i do that?

Comment: Not an Angular issue. More of a logic / JS Issue

Comment: What are inputs and outputs out of which the sums would be calculated?

Comment: Consider https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use array.reduce and find the total of each **`"Exit"`** and **`"Enter"`** and then find the difference between both,

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('MyModule', [])

.controller( 'MyController', function($scope){

    $scope.myjson = 
[   {
        "action1": "enter",
        "time": "13.00"
    },
    {
        "action2": "exit",
        "time": "13.20"
    },
    {
        "action1": "enter",
        "time": "13.50"
    },
    {
        "action2": "exit",
        "time": "15.00"
    },
    {
        "action1": "enter",
        "time": "16.00"
    },
    {
        "action2": "exit",
        "time": "20.00"
    }
];    
    
   $scope.sumByExit = function() {
    var total = 0;
    for (count = 0; count < $scope.myjson.length; count++) {
      if($scope.myjson[count].action1 === "exit")
      total += $scope.myjson[count].time;
    }
    return total
    }
    $scope.sumByEnter = function() {
    var total = 0;
    for (count = 0; count < $scope.myjson.length; count++) {
      if($scope.myjson[count].action1 === "enter")
      total += $scope.myjson[count].time;
    }
    return total
    }
   

    $scope.totalExit = $scope.sumByExit();   
    console.log($scope.totalExit);
    $scope.totalEnter = $scope.sumByEnter();
    $scope.totaldifference = parseInt($scope.totalExit) - parseInt($scope.totalEnter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller='MyController'>
 
    <p>Difference = {{totaldifference}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i mean ; total work 330min(5h30m),total break 90min(1h30m) i want to see that